# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error in console 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.' at line 18. I couldn't find any error in my js code, also when alert fires it doesn't go in one go infact it appears 2-3 times. Also my script file is at the end of the body.Please help me find the error.

```js
let editbox = document.getElementById('editbox');
let val = editbox.innerText;
let showAlert = document.getElementById('alrt');
let edit = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
let cl = document.getElementsByClassName('input')
editbox.addEventListener('click', clicked);

function clicked() {
    if (cl.length == 0) {
        editbox.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="input">';
        cl[0].value = val
    }
    showAlert.style.visibility = 'visible';
    
    cl[0].addEventListener('blur', function () {
        if(cl[0].value.length > 0){
        val = cl[0].value
        editbox.innerHTML = `<div class="edit">${val}</div>`;
        showAlert.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        } else {
            alert('You can not leave box empty')
        }

    })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    background-color: #83AF9B;
    border: 4px solid black;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.edit {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.alert{
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.input{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background: none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 2px;
    width: 97%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editable div</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box" id="editbox">
            <div class="edit">Click Here To Edit Me.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert" id="alrt">You can now edit it</div>
    </div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this condition is true: `if (cl.length == 0)` then what are you expecting this to do: `cl[0].value = val`  You're trying to edit the first element in an array after confirming that the array has no elements.

Comment: This condition: if (cl.length == 0) lets me to able edit within input else I wouldn't be able to.

Comment: More specifically, the condition `if (cl.length == 0)` validates that the length of `cl` is `0`.  The point is... You can't edit the first element of an empty array.  Because there is no first element.  Because the array is empty.

Comment: i got ur answer for u and working code for proof. NICE DESIGN BRO, saved it on my pc. also, whenever u see an error but the code is still working... it is ALWAYS an asynchronous problem so look there first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "problem" is with the event listener inside of the big function

the event listener is activated when there is a change in cl[0] and naturally you overwrite editbox.innerHTML when this listener is activated so it gets activated again (asynchronous logic)

the solution is simply saying if(cl[0] != undefined) {do rest of function}

my example is below (also prevents overlap of listeners)

```js
let editbox = document.getElementById('editbox');
let val = editbox.innerText;
let showAlert = document.getElementById('alrt');
let edit = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
var cl = document.getElementsByClassName('input')
editbox.addEventListener('click', clicked);

function clicked() {
    if (cl.length == 0) {
        editbox.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="input">';
        cl[0].value = val
    }
    showAlert.style.visibility = 'visible';
    
    function theEditor () {
      if(cl[0] != undefined){
        if(cl[0].value.length > 0){
        val = cl[0].value;
        editbox.innerHTML = `<div class="edit">${val}</div>`;
        showAlert.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        } else {
            alert('You can not leave box empty')
        }
      }
    }
    cl[0].removeEventListener('blur', theEditor)
    cl[0].addEventListener('blur', theEditor)
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
    background-color: #83AF9B;
    border: 4px solid black;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.edit {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.alert{
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.input{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background: none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 2px;
    width: 97%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editable div</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box" id="editbox">
            <div class="edit">Click Here To Edit Me.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert" id="alrt">You can now edit it</div>
    </div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot for helping me out bro. I'm a beginner and in a learning phase. Got a good hand on HTML and CSS but struggling in JavaScript